# Recovering an ext4 filesystem with corrupt journal

Tags: hard-disk, data-recovery, ext4

I have a hard drive that seems to have developed some kind of hardware problem in the journal. This prevents the drive from being loaded. Running `mount -r -t ext4 /dev/sda5 /mnt/root` results in the following kernel spew:

```
[ 1420.671055] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1000000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 1420.673862] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[ 1420.676600] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 1420.679326] ata1.00: cmd 60/40:c0:a8:9d:0a/00:00:08:00:00/40 tag 24 ncq 32768 in
[ 1420.679326]          res 41/40:40:e1:9d:0a/00:00:08:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 1420.685014] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 1420.687858] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 1420.761064] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 1420.763863] sd 0:0:0:0: >[sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 1420.766653] sd 0:0:0:0: >[sda]  
[ 1420.769364] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1420.772104] sd 0:0:0:0: >[sda]  
[ 1420.774780] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[ 1420.777491] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 1420.780249]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 1420.783175]         08 0a 9d e1 
[ 1420.785972] sd 0:0:0:0: >[sda]  
[ 1420.788730] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 1420.791545] sd 0:0:0:0: >[sda] CDB: 
[ 1420.794331] Read(10): 28 00 08 0a 9d a8 00 00 40 00
[ 1420.797242] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 134913505
[ 1420.800072] ata1: EH complete
[ 1420.800077] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 2748
[ 1420.812529] JBD2: recovery failed
[ 1420.815275] EXT4-fs (sda5): error loading journal
```

I barely understand what this means, but it sure looks like a hardware problem preventing the journal from being loaded. Is there anyway to work around this? Can the journal, say, be relocated to a different offset while leaving the rest of the drive mostly intact? I have no intention of continuing to use the drive; I just want to mount it so I can copy a few crucial files.

Comment: Two things: make sure to disconnect and reconnect the cables. If may even get rid of the hardware problem temporarily. If it does, get new cables. Otherwise also try the disk(s) in another computer with different cables.

Comment: Did you try to `fsck` the filesystem?

Comment: I had a similar issue today where I somehow managed to corrupt the journal when unlocking my encrypted ext4 partition. I could only mount as read only. I managed to fix it by running the 'Check' routine against the partition in GParted. The 'Check' routine found the problems with the journal and corrected them automatically.

Answer (score 11):

To mount it read-only, without replaying the journal so you can access your files (you will probably lose some changes which haven't yet been committed to the regular fs):

`mount -o ro,noload` ...

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at the output of `smartctl -a /dev/sda`. If it's not a cable problem then the disk may be dying. If you don't have a recent backup you should try to copy the block device content (without mounting) using dd_rescue or dd with respective options.

After that you may try `hdparm --write-sector` (always funny these "VERY DANGEROUS" options...).

Another option is to create a DM device which bypasses the defective sectors. That doesn't recover their contents, of course. You must convert the sda offset (134913505) into a sda5 offset (find out the number of the first sector of sda5 and subtract it). Let's assume the sda5 offset is 12345. You create a block device whose sector 12345 is not mapped to sda5 but somewhere else (e.g. loop device). The device definition (for dmsetup create) looks like this:

```
0 12345 linear /dev/sda5 0
12345 1 linear /dev/loop0 0
12346 99987653 /dev/sda5 12345

# format:
# logical_start_sector num_sectors linear destination_device start_sector
```

You will not be so lucky that there is only one defective sector. You can map out as many as you want (resulting in the DM device delivering zeros for those sectors but being writable) but calculation the offsets in loop0 may become fun. Another option would be to use a virtual device of the same size for remapping and use either thin provisioning or a snapshot (with small chunk size, 1 sector e.g.) of a zero target device.

**Edit 1**

The loop device should not point to a file on the same disk (sda), of course.

Comment: Very good point. `--write-sector` is *FAR* from "dangerous". In fact, this is actually the __ideal__ option to use whenever certain corrupt *single* sectors prevent you from getting a *continuous* raw sector image (`dd` would bail out with "Device I/O error"; some hdds will even require to __power-cycle__ the machine (!) to get recognized by the OS again). However, you __must__ know about shell-scripting if you want to use `--write-sector` for sector *ranges*.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot in recovery mode, in which the FS will be mounted read-only, and copy your stuff.

Comment: I am mounting read-only. I corrected the command-line shown above to make this clearer.

Comment: And can you access the drive?

Comment: No. Trying to mount the drive RO (or in R/W, it makes no difference) results in the error spew shown above.

Comment: Then the suggestion with the cable swap may come in handy. And regarding your question, the journal can't be moved the way you want.